# Triangles of the form $a^n+b^n=c^n$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $\Delta$ be a triangle with (real) sides length $a,b,c>0$. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735126/167226), we know that $$a+b=c \qquad \iff \qquad \Delta \text{ is a straight line}$$ Now, we know from the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Converse) that 
>   $$ a^2+b^2=c^2 \qquad \iff \qquad \Delta \text{ is a right triangle}$$
>   I'm wondering if it is possible, for a fixed $n>2$, to have a *geometric characterization* of the triangles which satisfy $a^n+b^n=c^n$, that is:
>   $$ a^n+b^n=c^n \qquad \iff \qquad \Delta \text{ is ?}.$$

**Notes:** For $n>1$, and any $a,b>0$ there exists always a non-degenerated triangle $\Delta$ with $c= (a^n+b^n)^{1/n}$. It seems that for the case $n=3$, things are already more complicated. All the following triangles satisfy 
$$a^3+b^3=c^3.$$
[image]

Comment: In general at least one of $a, b,c$ must be irrational otherwise this would contradict Fermat's Last Theorem

Comment: Well, note that you've got a correspondence between these triangles and right-angled triangles via the map $x\to x^{n/2}$. As this map is convex for $n>2$, I'm convinced your triangles will never have angles larger than $\pi/2$.

Comment: I don't think number-theory (or even elementary-number-theory) is an appropriate tag for this. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = \frac{a}{c}$, $y = \frac{b}{c}$ (note: both are in $(0, 1)$)

then for $n \gt 2$,

$x + y \gt x^2 + y^2 > x^n + y^n = 1$

Thus $a + b \gt c$ and $a^2 + b^2 \gt c^2$ and so $a,b,c$ form the sides of a triangle and the triangle must be acute.

Comment: The implication is one way. Note all acute triangles satisfy the criterion obviously.

Comment: This is a nice observation, but it does not *characterizes* the triangles for which $a^n+b^n = c^n$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @idm: I would say $a^n + b^n = c^n$ is actually a good characterization already! And no, you are not missing anything. I would not hope for some "elegant" characterization though... We could prove some properties like the triangle is acute etc, but trying to get a simpler characterization might be hopeless (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for any $m > 0$ there will exist $c^n = m$ and for any $j + k = m; j>0; k>0$ there will exist $a^n = j; b^n = k$.  As $(a+b)^n > a^n + b^n = c^n$ we have $a+b > c$ so such triangles exist and such numbers are very common.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from my answer. I have edited to make it clear. And +1 to you.

Comment: This is a nice observation, but it does not *characterizes* the triangles for which $a^n+b^n = c^n$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  But i thought once it was realized that such numbers were common and easy to solve the characteristics of such triangles would seem to be mundane and not worth characterizing.

Answer (score 1):

If we fix two points of the triangle at $(\pm 1,0)$ (and therefore $c=2$), then we can plot the points satisfying $a+b=2$, $a^2+b^2=2^2$ like [this WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)%3D2%5E1) and [this WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(2%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(2%2F2)%3D2%5E2).

Likewise, we can plot the cases for $n=3,4,5$ and $10$. ([$n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)%3D2%5E3), [$n=4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(4%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(4%2F2)%3D2%5E4), [$n=5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(5%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(5%2F2)%3D2%5E5), [$n=10$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(10%2F2)%2B((x%2B1)%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E(10%2F2)%3D2%5E10))

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice observation. This suggests somehow that there should exists a Thales theorem holding for ellipses instead of circles.