# Triangles of the Form $a^n+b^n=c^n$ are always an acute

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Is there a way to prove the result that every triangle of the form $a^n+b^n=c^n$ are always an acute without the result FLT. Every proof I have found instantly requires them to not all be integers due to FLT.

Comment: This has nothing to do with number theory. Under your condition, namely $\left( a^n + b^n \right)^{1/n} =c,$ is $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$ smaller, equal to, or larger than $c \; ? \; $

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm

Comment: I mean it is equal to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239150/triangles-of-the-form-anbn-cn

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"...triangle of the form $a^n+b^n=c^n$..."*.

Answer (score 1):

Example: if $x,y > 0$   and $x^2 + y^2 = 1, $
then $x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 = 1$ and $x^4 + y^4 < 1.$ Thus if $x^4 + y^4 = 1,$  we know $x^2 + y^2 >1.$ Same thing: if $a^4 + b^4 = c^4,$  then $a^2 + b^2 > c^2.$ What does the Law of Cosines say about the angle between the $a$  and $b$ sides.

For the original $a^n + b^n = c^n,$  we see that $c$ is the longest side. It is opposite the largest angle, call that $\theta.$ The proof that the longest side is opposite the largest angle combines the Law of Sines and the Law of Cosines.

As long as $n > 2$ we also have $c^2 < a^2 + b^2.$ Next

$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta  $$ and
$$  a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta < a^2 + b^2 $$
$$ - 2ab \cos \theta < 0 $$
$$   2ab \cos \theta > 0 $$

$$    \cos \theta > 0 $$
That is, $\theta$ is an acute angle. It is also the largest angle, so the other two angles are acute

[image]

picture.................................

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That make sense.